# Jsonify Exception errors

Tags: python-3.x, flask, error-handling, flask-restful, rest

While trying to handle errors in Flask Rest API, i would like to return the json version of error message and status code. i tried the following

```
@app.route("/model/test/",methods=["GET"])
def show():
    try:
        num=request.args['num']
        return jsonify({'result':num,'response':'200 OK'})
    except Exception as e:


        return jsonify({'error':e})
```

and when i hit the `GET` method with `http://localhost:5000/model/test/?ummm=30`. i got a error exceptions can't be jsonified 
any help on how to give error output as i wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json does not support many formats. Python decoding/encoding rules can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). I would propose to extract the text from the exception and add a status code, maybe `"error" : "Message: {}, status 400 Bad request".format(e)`? Or you can add a `status-code` separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example:

```
def my_function():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        try:
            a_test_function(request)
            return {
                'message': 'Request is a good request.',
                'status': 200,
            }, 200
        except ValueError as error:
            return {
                'message': "Bad request!",
                'status': 400,
                'Error': str(error),
            }, 400
        except:
            return {
                'message': "Bad request!",
                'status': 400,
                'Error': 'Unexpected error.',
            }, 400
```